# Excel sheeet shows #### in cells while retrive data from mysql in php

Tags: mysql, excel

I am using this header

```
  //This Header is used to make data download instead of display the data 
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$setExcelName."_Reoprt.xls");
```

Comment: Please past the codes you prepared your data for excel.

Comment: Perhaps the data is wider than the column

Comment: Widen the column or use the equivalent of `.EntireColumn.AutoFit`.